# Display Extbase FileReference with Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In an extbase extension, I have a FileReference Object. It was created with extension_builder originally.
From The Model:

```
/**
 * apprenticeshipDocument
 *
 @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
 */
protected $apprenticeshipDocument = NULL;
```

etc.

In the frontend, `<f:debug>{institution.apprenticeshipDocument}</f:debug>` gives me this:

[image: Extbase Var Dump]

First Thing: `originalResource` is missing.

Second: When calling {institution.apprenticeshipDocument.uidLocal} directly, the value is NULL! Although it's said to be 450 above.

Third: Let's say we could get uidLocal, which corresponds to the uid in sys_file.

The googlable solution:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{f:uri.image(src:450)}" target="_blank">Text</f:link.page>
```

doesn't point to the PDF file itself, but to a rendered GIF of the PDF.
All I want to do is output the path to the file (`sys_file.identifier`) in a link... there must be a way, mustn't it?

EDIT: Solution provided by Jost:

```
<f:if condition="{institution.apprenticeshipDocument}">
    <li>
    <f:link.page pageUid="{institution.apprenticeshipDocument.originalResource.publicUrl}" target="_blank">Text</f:link.page>
    </li>
</f:if>
```

Comment: Maybe related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/48965 ? But I'm on 6.2.12, where the patch seems to be included

Comment: Ah just found https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/198281/ will look into that

Comment: That's the one!! Will post answer later (hopefully...)

Comment: `originalResource` is lazy-loaded, so it is correct to be `NULL`. Just access it. I believe you can also access it and then do the f:debug to see all its fields. One of them will be `originalFile`, which is also lazy-loaded.

Comment: Reason for `uidLocal` not being accessible is probably that there is no getter for it, so fluid can't read it. To link the file, I usually use the `v:link.typolink` ViewHelper from EXT:vhs, which you can use like this: `<v:link.typolink configuration="{parameter: 'file:{variableContainingUid}'}>Linktext</v:link.typoscript>`. Alternatively, you could use `{institution.apprenticeshipDocument.originalResource.publicUrl}` to get the URL (not sure about the exact name).

Comment: About the lazy-Loading: awesome, thanks!

Comment: About vhs: Ah, of course, great. Vhs to the rescue. But sometimes I tend to avoid dependencies for better maintainability. Now I have `<f:link.page pageUid="fileadmin/{institution.apprenticeshipDocument.originalResource.originalFile.identifier}" target="_blank"><f:translate key="tx_stellen_domain_model_institution.apprenticeship_document" /></f:link.page>` which is ok as this site only has one file storage.  I've tried to get the full path with `<f:debug>{institution.apprenticeshipDocument.originalResource.originalFile.storage}</f:debug>`- but no luck again

Comment: I think that is worse for maintainability than using `EXT:vhs` - you are depending on the info that there is a storage in the folder `fileadmin`, and it is the one storage your file is in. You also assume that the file identifier has something to do with the URL of the file, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Try to use the `publicUrl`-property of the file (or reference) instead - there is a [getter](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/interface_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_file_interface.html#acba22af55b6e8e0d7ab7282e932fca0c) for it in the fileInterface, so both file and file reference have that property. Also, there are more properties available, that you can't see in the debug output, mostly metadata - they are accessed using a magic getter.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Can you post the solution (see above) as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files and file references behave a bit different in fluid than usual:

1. They are lazy-loaded, so the `originalResource` (Extbase file reference) and `originalFile` (Core file reference) values are `NULL` before the first access to them. But you can just access them as usual.
2. The value `uidLocal` of an extbase file reference can't be accessed because there is no getter for it (as of TYPO3 6.2.12 and 7.2).
3. To get the url of a file, use its `publicUrl` attribute, or use the ViewHelper `v:link.typolink` from EXT:vhs, like this:

   ```
   <v:link.typolink configuration="{parameter: 'file:{uid}'}>
       Linktext
   </v:link.typolink>
   ```

   `uid` is the id of the file in this case.
4. Many properties of files (especially metadata-properties) are not saved as normal object attributes, but are internally saved into an associative array and then fetched using a magic getter. They are also lazy-loaded. Thus, they usually don't show up as separate properties in variable dumps, and may be not set at all or `NULL` (same as above).